# Counting associated objects from an array of parent objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working a report that counts neighbors in a household - I am looking at using either a helper method, simple query or both

A household is an object that has several neighbors and I want to count the total number of neighbors in a select group of households. I have an array of households IDs:

```
@household_ids = [31, 15, 30, 38, 1, 5, 32, 25, 10, 26, 14,29]
```

I tried this:

```
def household_neighbor_count(houses)
   houses.each  do |id| 
   @neigh  = Household.find(id).neighbor_count
   @neigh
  end
end
```

Which doesn't work - it returns a list of the IDs

Since this is Rails I could also do an activerecord query and this is my shot in pseudo sql:

```
 Neighbors where household_id == household_id in @household-ids
```

I am using squeel if that helps

How do  I do this either -approach is fine or a recommendation of the best approach is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do, but I guess this is what you want:

```
houses.map{|id| Household.find(id).neighbor_count}.inject(:+)
```

If there are duplicates within the neighbors among the houses, then you need a method to get the set of neighbors for a given house, not just the count. And since you have not shown such method, I guess either that is not an issue, or your question is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming there are household_id in Neighbor model

```
@household_ids = [31, 15, 30, 38, 1, 5, 32, 25, 10, 26, 14,29]
total_number_of_neighbors = Neighbor.where('household_id IN (?)', @household_ids).count
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
Household.includes(:neighbors).select('households.id, neighbors.id').where(:id => [31, 15, 30, 38, 1, 5, 32, 25, 10, 26, 14,29]).map{|r| {r.id =>  r.neighbors.count}}
```